# Formal Parameters difference between sendto() and recvfrom() in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, sendto, recvfrom

I am using [`recvfrom()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) and [`sendto()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) for receiving and sending UDP packets.

I have noticed that `recvfrom()` as last parameter requires **a pointer to the variable** storing the length of server address while `sendto()` requires **the variable** that stores the length of the client address.

Why there is this difference?

Comment: Have you tried to read the descriptions of the functions?

Comment: Receive wants to put the size it read somewhere; send only needs to know the length and won't modify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since UDP is not connection based (there's not a `connect(sd, ...)` call in which you say: from now on all data related to socket descriptor `sd` will come from a well known IP-port couple), whenever you issue `recvfrom()` it will (try to) return you the address from where incoming data origins.

It writes the address in *src_addr* buffer, if it is not NULL. This buffer is provided by the caller and its size must be specified setting *addr_len* parameter. It is passed by pointer because `recvfrom()`, after using it to limit the amount of data written in *src_addr*, will overwrite it with the **actual** address length. We can say that *addr_len* is an input-output parameter.

The caller of `sendto()`, on the other side, will exactly know the destination address, so *addr_len* in this case is passed by value because is an input-only parameter.

This information is clearly explained in the guide you linked in the question.

Comment: Thank you! I got lost through the jargon words and thus the guide was not really useful. So the reason is that the **actual** address length is known due to UDP network of not being connection based. Thus we are passing by pointer because this value can be modified.

Comment: Actually **there _is_ an option to call connect() on UDP** to specify the (only) remote address (but not actually communicate like TCP does with the SYN/ACK exchange) and subsequently use send() and recv() with that address implicit; see https://linux.die.net/man/7/udp et rel. But sendto() recvfrom() sendmsg() recvmsg() _without_ connect() are more commonly used and work as you describe.

Answer (score 3):

> I have noticed that recvfrom() as last parameter requires a pointer to
>   the variable storing the length of server address while sendto()
>   requires the variable that stores the length of the client address.

You actually answering your own question

```
recvfrom() as last parameter requires a pointer to
the variable storing the length of server address.


while sendto() requires the variable that stores 
the length of the client address.
```

`recvfrom()` needs pointer because it is storing the value to the location where that pointer is pointing . Since in `c` there is nothing called call by reference you need to pass the pointer to simulate call-by-reference behavior.

Comment: That's basically correct, but note that "call-by-reference" is a quite general/abstract concept, which one can see as being _implemented_ by passing pointers as function arguments in C. So, it is quite ok to say "c supports call by reference"

Comment: @Ctx no that's wrong. C only support call-by-value. You can emulate call-by-ref passing pointers, but that does not make C supporting it (it isn't native to the language).

Comment: Thank you Kiran Biradar for your answer and thank Jean-Baptise Yunes. Why recvfrom needs the location where the pointer is pointing while sendto does not?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That's a very narrow sight on those concepts, typical for programmers.